# PHP get javascript variable value

Tags: php, javascript

At first i have this script

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(work){
            document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML="<?php 

            *$job = work;*

            $sql="INSERT INTO event ( id, name, job, status)
             VALUES
             ('','$_SESSION[username]','$job','not verified')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql); 
            ?>";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick='test(job1)'>&nbsp&nbsp  Add  &nbsp&nbsp</button>
</body>
```

i need to pass the work value from javascript to $job in php.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well first of it's plain wrong to put php code inside javascript, now as for your question, you need to use `AJAX` for that i highly recommend jquery for that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: [Please learn the difference between client and server side](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcBB2Fp8WNI).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Granted you are new - please review [The Guidelines](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Errrrr... thanks for the answer.
sorry for my stupidity
And thanks for the FAQ to show me my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Javascript (in this case) lives in your browser. PHP lives on the server side. These two languages can't interact directly with each other. The PHP is evaluated before the browser even sees the page content.

You can use an AJAX request to send information to the server which is then handled by PHP on the server side. I strongly suggest using a proper Javascript library to handle AJAX requests, such as jQuery or one of the many alternatives.

Another possibility is to submit a form which sends the information to the server side, where PHP handles it as suggested.

Comment: so it's impossible to passing data between javascript and PHP without AJAX. 

thanks for the answer and quick response

Comment: From Javascript to PHP; yes. From PHP to Javascript you could generate the javascript dynamically with the values you want passed, although that would only work when the page is generated for the first time. Remember to accept answers, btw :-)